# Statistical test recommendation for efficacy of three different drugs with categorical responses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, logistic, chi-squared-test

I have a really small study sample of 70, in which they are being medicated with 3 different drugs (A,B,C). The study aimed to determine the efficacy of each drug in treating the disease and the outcome of treatment is either success or failure. I have tried analysing the data using the chi-square test and fisher's exact test, however, my supervisor advised me on using the logistic regression test. Would that be possible to carry that out with a small study sample, with which all variables are categorical?

| Treatment | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Success | 23 | 11 | 12 |
| Failure | 12 | 5 | 7 |

(Very new to stats)

Update :
Hypothesis - Drug A is more effective than Drug B or Drug C in treating the condition

Comment: Is the disease chronic or acute? Don't you have the timing of success or failure after  the start of this disease (if acute) or start of treatment (if chronic)?

Comment: What is your research hypothesis with respect to those three drugs? They are identical/A is better than either B or C/something else?

Comment: The nature of your data doesn't allow for any regression, because you don't have any numerical variables (only counts within categories, i.e., a contingency table), which, yes, leads you to chi square and Fisher's exact test if your hypothesis is: there is no difference between any of those three drugs (this hypothesis is rare).

Comment: The aim is to determine which drug is the most effective. But my current null hypothesis is that drug A is more effective than drug B and C. Is there any statistical analysis that I can verify my hypothesis?

Comment: You may mean that your current null hypotheses are that drug A is *not* more effective than drug B and drug A is *not* more effective than drug C (which need to be rejected).

Comment: Yea sorry, confused myself.

Comment: Do you have timing for the outcome success or failure for each study subject? Like subject 001 developed failure on day 10, subject 002 developed failure on day 16, subject 003 hasn't developed failure until the end of his/her participation (which was on day 120).

Comment: The timing of the outcome was observed during final re-exam, with which if the disease is present, the treatment is failed.

Comment: Too bad that you don't have timing, it would dramatically increase the sensitivity of your study with such a small dataset and so small difference in efficacy. I added my answer considering this scenario.

Comment: Let's say I have the date the treatment first started, and the final day of treatment is the day the study observed the presence of disease, hence I would have the duration of treatment. Could this piece of data add any value to the current analysis?

Comment: I think it will make sense only if the disease status is checked periodically pretty frequently, and our knowledge of when the outcome happened is relatively precise.

Comment: Fair. Anyways, thank you so much for your help Alex!

Answer (score 1):

To test pairwise drug A vs drug B and drug A vs drug C for superiority of drug A, you may want to conduct one-tail Fisher's exact tests between those pairs. In R, it will be:

```r
data <- matrix(c(23, 11, 12, 12, 5, 7), nrow=3, byrow=FALSE)
fisher.test(data[1:2,], alternative = "greater")
fisher.test(data[c(1,3),], alternative = "greater")
```

P.S. There is absolutely no statistical significance in these tests (the superiority of drug A vs either drug B or C is not supported).

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use logistic regression to estimate the three treatment effects and then test the one-sided hypothesis that A is more effective that B and C. One benefit of this approach is that it's straightforward to include covariates (if you have any).

In your case, however, the summary table clearly suggests there is no difference between the drugs: there are 23 successes in 35 patients treated with A and also 23 successes in another 35 patients treated with B or C. The success rates is about 66% for all three drugs.

Nevertheless, let's back this up by fitting a logistic regression to the data and then looking at the [contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics)) which compares the effectiveness of A to the average effectiveness of B and C.

```r
library("contrast")

aggregated <- data.frame(
  treatment = c("A", "B", "C"),
  successes = c(23, 11, 12),
  failures = c(12, 5, 7)
)
individual <- data.frame(
  treatment = c(
    rep(aggregated$treatment, aggregated$successes),
    rep(aggregated$treatment, aggregated$failures)
  ),
  success = c(
    rep(1L, sum(aggregated$successes)),
    rep(0L, sum(aggregated$failures))
  )
)
```

```r
# We can fit the model to the aggregate data by concatenating counts of 0s and 1s.
# But the `contrast` function doesn't compute the degrees of freedom correctly.
m0 <- glm(
  cbind(successes, failures) ~ treatment,
  family = binomial,
  data = aggregated
)
# So let's fit the model to the disaggregated, individual-level data.
# This data format can also handle covariates in a straightfoward way.
m1 <- glm(
  success ~ treatment,
  family = binomial,
  data = individual
)
contrast(
  m1,
  list(treatment = "A"),
  list(treatment = c("B", "C")),
  type = "average"
)
#> glm model parameter contrast
#> 
#>      Contrast      S.E.     Lower     Upper     t df Pr(>|t|)
#> 1 -0.01313936 0.5060498 -1.023219 0.9969403 -0.03 67   0.9794
```

`(Lower,Upper)` is the two-sided confidence interval for the contrast (comparison) between A and the average of B and C. However, since the *t* statistic is negative (*t* = -0.03), we know that the one-sided confidence interval includes 0 as well: the data is consistent with the null hypothesis that A is as effective as B and C.

```r
# Two-sided confidence interval
-0.01313936 + qt(.975, 67) * 0.5060498 * c(-1, 1)
#> [1] -1.0232190  0.9969403
# One-sided confidence interval
-0.01313936 + qt(.95, 67) * 0.5060498 * c(-1, Inf)
#> [1] -0.857188       Inf
```